# Accessing a function stored in an object on server-side from client-side

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, socket.io

Server-side:

```
//When a player connects, all the players will get this message.
    game.sockets.emit('entrance', 
        {
            id: socket.id,
            players: [],
            message: 'Player ' + socket.id + ' is online', 
            store: function(id, object){
                this.players.push({id: id, object: object});
            }
        });
```

Client-side:

```
socket.on('entrance', function(data){
        console.log(data.message);

        data.store(data.id, new Car('hero').init());    
    });
```

This gives me the following error:

[image]

It `console.log`'s the message stored in the object without a problem, so It seems like the error somewhere inside the function.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot transfer functions over the wire, they are not serialisable as JSON. Your `data` object will simply not contain a `store` property. Attach it on the clientside whenever you get a `entrance` event (or build a whole `Player` instance from it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With socket.io, you're sending JSON objects over the wire, and JSON doesn't support the sending of functions: http://www.json.org/

See this post full a detailed approach to do what you're trying to do: [Sending anonymous functions through socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865233/sending-anonymous-functions-through-socket-io) (the post talks specifically about anonymous functions, but the same holds true for what you're attempting).